# Returning the time and date of a sent email - IMAP

Tags: python, imap

New to python and I've been trying to create a program that returns the time a specific email was received and couldn't find a function anywhere that did so. (So far I've checked reddit, Stack Overflow and Automate the Boring stuff) I've been able to return the body of the email with the below but couldn't find anything on whether or not I can extract only the time from emails. Any help on if this is possible and how it can be done would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

```
password = input('Enter your password')
import imapclient
server = imapclient.IMAPClient('imap-mail.outlook.com', ssl=True)
server.login('myemail@msn.com',password)
import pprint
pprint.pprint(server.list_folders())
server.select_folder('Inbox')
rawMessage = server.fetch(40111, ['BODY[]'])
import pyzmail
message = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(rawMessage[40111][b'BODY[]'])
messagebodyTEXT = message.text_part.get_payload().decode(message.text_part.charset)
print(messagebodyTEXT)
```

Comment: You can get the Date header from the email, but that is set by the senter.  Instead of fetching 'BODY[]' and parsing an email, try fetching 'INTERNALDATE', which is the servers timestamp of when it got the message.  Read RFC3501 S6.4.5 for all the things you can `FETCH`.

Comment: the INTERNALDATE worked, I'm interested in learning about what more I can fetch and will check that out. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The library that you're using is talking the IMAP protocol. In IMAP, there's no such thing as a "time when a message was received". There's a timestamp on when that message was ["stored into the mailbox (`INTERNALDATE`)"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-57), but that's a something else in the generic case.

You could also try to parse the [`Received`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.7) headers which might (or might not) contain the information that you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

building on previous comments and answers regarding INTERNALDATE, here is the code snippet I used to retrieve the delivered date and transform it to a datetime object, with the imaplib library:

```
>>> import imaplib
>>> connection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('yourimapserver')
>>> response = connection.login('youremailaddress', 'password')
>>> connection.select('INBOX')
>>> status, data = connection.fetch(b'1', '(INTERNALDATE)') # b"1" is your uid
```

From there, different options depending on:

- the format of the datetime your imap server provides,
- whether you need a timezone aware object.

**timezone naive**

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import time

>>> data[0]
b'1 (INTERNALDATE "12-Aug-2020 16:38:19 +0200")'
>>> timestruct = imaplib.Internaldate2tuple(data[0])
>>> timestruct
time.struct_time(tm_year=2020, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=12,tm_hour=16, tm_min=38, tm_sec=19, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=225, tm_isdst=1)
>>> datetime_delivered = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(timestruct))
>>> datetime_delivered
datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 12, 16, 38, 19)
```

**timezone aware (Python 3.2+)**

```
>>> import email
>>> str_datetime = data[0].decode().split('"')[1]
>>> str_datetime
"12-Aug-2020 16:38:19 +0200"
>>> timezone_aware = email.utils.parsedate_to_datetime(str_datetime)
>>> timezone_aware
datetime.datetime(2020,8, 12, 16, 38, 19, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using the `pyzmail` third-party library, but did you know there's an extensive `email` module in the Python standard library?

Specifically I think the parser is what you'll want for extracting timestamps:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html